# Using Export-Mailbox without including subfolders

Tags: powershell, exchange-2007

I want to delete a certain group of messages from somebody's mailbox.  I already have the basic Powershell command ready to go:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity jshmoe | Export-Mailbox -SubjectKeywords "VirusWarning" -IncludeFolders "\Inbox" -StartDate "02/24/2010" -DeleteContent
```

The problem is that Joe Shmoe's "Inbox" is **huge**, and I know the messages I want to delete are only in the main Inbox folder.  However, the above Powershell command appears to crawl all subfolders beneath "Inbox".  Is there a way to tell it not to?

Comment: You might want to ask this on ServerFault.com since it's more SysAdmin related.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `-IncludeFolders` parameter, look at the examples [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266964%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx.). Be aware that you may need to specify the folder name in the different languages your users may be using, e.g. -IncludeFolders "\Inbox","\Bandeja de Entrada" for English+Spanish.

Comment: link is dead "here"

Answer (score 1):

looks like this was intended behaviour, but a workaround is shown [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/benw/archive/2010/07/26/exchange-2007-and-export-mailbox-with-the-includefolders-switch.aspx)

essentially you build a variable containing a list of the folders you want to exclude...

```
$r = [regex]'/';
$exclude = Get-Mailbox -Identity jshmoe | Get-MailboxFolderStatistics | where {$_.folderpath -ne "/" -and $_.FolderPath -ne "/Inbox"} | Select-Object FolderPath | Foreach {$_.folderpath.tostring()} | foreach {$r.replace($_”,”\”,-1)}
```

then build up your typical `Export-Mailbox` command with an exclude instead.